# Skype intergration in web app

Tags: virtual, skype

hi I would like to integrate Skype in to my web application where our staff can call customers using Skype ( click to call) . this web app is an internal application , basically i want the staff to click on the phone number and start calling using the headset from the browser. it doesn't matter if its Skype or any other soft-phone system . any advice would be helpful. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply make a link like this to initiate a Skype call.

```
<a href="callto://+132465798">Call customer</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Skype offers a good API and documentation for developer, watch here: https://developer.skype.com/skype-uri